# Creating totals for invoices in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm hoping someone's able to help me with this, as my level of knowledge in Access is not up to the task.

I have two tables that have a one-to-many relationship:

**tblInvoice** contains the following fields:

- InvoiceNumber (primary key)
- Subtotal
- GSTTotal
- Total

**tblInvoiceItem** contains the following fields:

- InvoiceNumber
- Description
- AmountExGST
- GSTAmount
- AmountIncGST

I'd like to be able to fill the fields 'Subtotal', 'GSTTotal' and 'Total' from tblInvoice with the sums of 'AmountExGST', 'GSTAmount' and 'AmountIncGST' respectively whilst restricting this process to individual invoices.

An example would be:

Invoice #13 has two items worth $50 with $5 GST each listed in **tblInvoiceItem**. I'd like for Subtotal to show $100, GSTTotal to show $10 and Total to show $110 in **tblInvoice**.

Hopefully this makes enough sense for someone to help me :)

Comment: Do you need to store the Subtotal, GSTtotal and total in the tblInvoice ???, cant you just calculate it from tblInvoiceItem when needed ???. The current design breaks normal DB-Desgin criteria of reducing redundancy in a Data-Base. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Please paste one sample row of both tables

Comment: Bruce, I read the wikipedia article. A lot of it goes over my head, but what I'm gathering from it is that my approach is more complicated than necessary. Is that correct?

Comment: @VikasHardia, I couldn't get the table to paste nicely, so I hope a screenshot will suffice: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozd6zckzbzgkx6i/Tables.PNG

The parent table is mostly unfilled at this stage, as I'm trying to work the above problem out.

Comment: still not clear with data provided please paste two rows of tblInvoiceItem  table and related row for tblInvoice with same InvoiceNumber ...

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this sql query may help you. This sql query work fine for me.

```
(SELECT SUM((AmountExGST)+(GSTAmount)+(AmountIncGST)) FROM tblInvoiceItem WHERE tblInvoiceItem.InvoiceNumber=tblInvoice.InvoiceNumber) AS Subtotal
```